# Linux cut and add the output at the beginning of the same file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

For example, I have a file with name file1 and the contents are as below

```
var/lib/repos/main1:v1 2gb
var/lib/repos/main2:v2 1gb
…
```

So I want the output to be as follows

```
main1 var/lib/repos/main1:v1 2gb
main2 var/lib/repos/main2:v2 1gb
```

I tried the following command:

```
cut -d’/‘ -f 4 | cut -d”:” -f1 file1
```

Comment: Where do `main1` and `main2` come from?

Comment: looks like a fairly simple job for awk. Have you tried anything? What specific issue are you facing?

Comment: Is it just taking the base-name of the path and adding it as column1?

Comment: I was able cut the line using the delimiter -d but I’m not sure on how to add that output at the beginning of each line

Comment: Click on [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74019626/edit) link and add your attempted command.

Comment: @njzk2 could you please share the command using awk? Since I’m trying to use “ cut -d “ unable to achieve the expected result

Comment: @anubhava I’ve added the command that I tried

Comment: Your command seems to have non-ASCII quotes, is that a transcription error, or the reason for your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You may consider this `sed` solution:

```bash
sed -E 's~.*/([^:]+):.*~\1 &~' file

main1 var/lib/repos/main1:v1 2gb
main2 var/lib/repos/main2:v2 1gb
```

**Breakup:**

- `.*`: Match 0 or more of any char (longest match due to greediness)
- `/`: Match a `/`
- `([^:]+)`: Match 1+ of any char that is not `/` and capture in group #1
- `:`: Match a `:`
- `.*`: Match 0 or more of any char (longest match due to greediness)
- `\1 &`: Place first group's capture value and space in front of matched line

Or else this `awk` command would also work:

```bash
awk -F: 'n=split($1, a, /\//) {print a[n], $0}' file

main1 var/lib/repos/main1:v1 2gb
main2 var/lib/repos/main2:v2 1gb
```

Comment: Happy to note that it worked out, [you may mark an answer as accepted by clicking on **tick mark** on top-left of the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/160242)

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'match($0, /main[0-9]/) { print substr( $0, RSTART, RLENGTH ) " " $0}' file1

main1 var/lib/repos/main1:v1 2gb
main2 var/lib/repos/main2:v2 1gb
```